# How to run cmd command under administrator rights?

Tags: c#

How I can run below command under administrator approval in visual c#? Also I need to hide console windows while running console.

Thanks.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=HotSpot key=12345678";
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        Process wifiStart = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo wifiStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        wifiStartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
        wifiStartInfo.Arguments = "/C wlan start hostednetwork";
        wifiStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        wifiStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        wifiStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.StartInfo = wifiStartInfo;
        wifiStart.Start();
    }
```

Comment: open command line as administrator?

Comment: This isn't the same question asked in 40 minutes ago (which is deleted by OP)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445599/running-cmd-commands-with-administrator-approval

Comment: Your previous question was closed for the exact same reason as Yuriy suggests...

Comment: i'm newbie for this forum and visual c#. therefore i can't understand well content of previously post.

Answer (score 4):

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo {
    FileName = "netsh",
    Arguments = "wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=HotSpot key=12345678",
    Verb = "runas",
    UseShellExecute = true,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
});
```

This starts a process using the "runas" verb, which makes the shell try to execute it in elevated privileges mode. But we actually need the shell to be involved in this in the first place, hence the `UseShellExecute = true` value.

The last property tells the shell to hide the new process' window, but I'm not sure this will work for a console program.

Comment: i used above command to resolve my problem.. but it can't do it...

Comment: when i copy that command to my project the visual c# IDE is show some error

Comment: What error? Please be explicit and precise.

Comment: IDE show red underline in FileName,Arguments,Verb, UseShellExecute and WindowStyle

Comment: Oh, yeah, there was a typo in my code, sorry. I've updated the answer.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: You're right, it's a big overlook.